# Почему не выводится текст из инпута?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Создаю чат. Необходимо вывести текст из инпута. Написал код, но он почему-то не выводит текст из инпута. Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему

```js
function input() {
  var input_taker = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = input_taker;
}
```

```css
.chat {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
   <div class="msg" id="msg">
    
   </div>
  <div class="send-line">
    <div class="get-name">
      <p>введите ваше имя</p>
      <input type="text"  id="input">
    </div>
    <div class="get-msg">
      <p>введите ваш текст</p>
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <button>Отправить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: два инпута с одинаковым идентификатором - это подсказка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас два элемента с `id="input"`, поэтому программа не знает откуда брать текст. И вы не навесили обработчик событий на [кнопку](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events). Правда я не обработчика навесила, а просто использовала аттрибут `onclick`

```js
function input() {
  var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var input_msg = document.getElementById('input_msg').value;
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = `${username}: ${input_msg}`;
}
```

```css
.chat {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
   <div class="msg" id="msg">
    
   </div>
  <div class="send-line">
    <div class="get-name">
      <p>введите ваше имя</p>
      <input type="text"  id="username">
    </div>
    <div class="get-msg">
      <p>введите ваш текст</p>
      <input type="text" id="input_msg">
      <button onclick="input()">Отправить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое за столь развёрнутый ответ, очень помогли!

Comment: Рада, что смогла помочь, удачи)